# What does <> mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this piece of code I programmed months ago:

```
@shipments = Shipment.joins(:invoice).where(:customer_id => @customer.id).where("customer_open_balance <> 0").order("file_number ASC")
```

I forgot what `<>` means. I searched online and looked through my Pickaxe book and can't find the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<>` is [SQL](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/comparison-operators/comparison-not-equal-to-operator.php), and means "not equal to", a.k.a. `!=`